# Checking and displaying files with os.walk()

Tags: python

The intended purpose of the program is to walk through the operating system's directories starting from `path` and collect every file while passing it to the `check()` function.  This function seems to work fine in printing every file even if the `check()` line was replaced with a simple `print(file)` so where am I going wrong in executing this?  Should I be storing all files in a list and then afterwards reading from that list to perform my actions?

```
for paths, subdirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
    for file in files:
        check(file)
```

Comment: Is the indentation in the code correct?

Comment: Read the `os.walk` documentation to see how it's done correctly.

Comment: Yeah I just discovered scandir which seems to be a big improvement anyways so I will look at that and how it can be implemented instead.  I've been reading the documentation but am struggling to understand why this is not working so thanks for that super helpful comment.  And yes, the indentation is correct in the actual code, the copy/paste seemed to mess it up.

Comment: Well the documentation is quite clear, both in its text and in its examples, that you need to join the names with the given dirpath. Which you're not doing. So not a big surprise it works in the start path (you probably use `.`?) but nowhere deeper.

Comment: Then maybe simply say 'join the full paths' instead of saying 'check the documentation.'  Not even worth the time you spent typing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, you need the filepath, not the filename.

```
for paths, subdirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
    for file in files:
        check(os.path.join(paths, file))
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I just realized and did myself.  Thank you for the assistance.